Getting a field from a nest object durring the projection on an aggregation in mongoose
I have created a somewhat complex aggregation (which I find complex) where I gather all the necessary documents into one. My question is: how can I retrieve the message field from a postContent object that is added to the comments? Below is the aggregation, written in NestJS with Mongoose:
const pages = await this.facebookPageModel.aggregate([
  // Stage 1: Match the specific Facebook page by _id
  {
    $match: { _id },
  },

  // Stage 2: Lookup the channel details for the page
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'channels',
      localField: 'channel',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'channel',
    },
  },

  // Stage 3: Unwind the channel array to destructure the channel details
  {
    $unwind: '$channel',
  },

  // Stage 4: Lookup channel posts related to the Facebook page
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'channelposts',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'fbPage',
      as: 'channelPosts',
    },
  },

  // Stage 5: Unwind the channelPosts array to destructure individual channel posts
  {
    $unwind: '$channelPosts',
  },

  // Stage 6: Lookup posts linked to each channel post
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'posts',
      localField: 'channelPosts.post',
      foreignField: '_id',
      as: 'posts',
    },
  },

  // Stage 7: Unwind the posts array to destructure individual post details
  {
    $unwind: '$posts',
  },

  // Stage 8: Add fields from channelPosts to each post
  {
    $addFields: {
      'posts.likes': '$channelPosts.likes',
      'posts.comments': '$channelPosts.comments',
      'posts.shares': '$channelPosts.shares',
      'posts.publishDate': '$channelPosts.publishDate',
      'posts.status': '$channelPosts.status',
      'posts.channelPostId': '$channelPosts._id', // Add channelPost ID to post
    },
  },

  // Stage 9: Group the results by Facebook page _id
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      posts: { $push: '$posts' },          // Collect all posts into an array
      channelPosts: { $push: '$channelPosts' },  // Collect all channelPosts into an array
      channel: { $first: '$channel' },     // Keep the first channel details
      page: { $first: '$$ROOT' },          // Keep the entire original document (page)
    },
  },

  // Stage 10: Lookup comments linked to each channel post
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: 'comments',
      localField: 'channelPosts._id',
      foreignField: 'channelPost',
      as: 'pageComments',
    },
  },

  // Stage 11: Unwind the pageComments array to destructure individual comment details
  {
    $unwind: '$pageComments',
  },

  // Stage 12: Add postContent field to each comment, mapping it to the corresponding post
  {
    $addFields: {
      'pageComments.postContent': {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: '$posts',
              as: 'post',
              cond: {
                $eq: ['$$post.channelPostId', '$pageComments.channelPost'],
              },
            },
          },
          0,
        ],
      },
    },
  },

  // Stage 13: Group again by Facebook page _id to format the output
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$_id',
      posts: { $first: '$posts' },          // Keep the first post array
      channel: { $first: '$channel' },      // Keep the first channel details
      page: { $first: '$page' },            // Keep the first page details
      pageComments: { $push: '$pageComments' },  // Collect all comments into an array
    },
  },

  // Stage 14: Project the final shape of the documents for the output
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,   // Include _id field
      channel: {   // Structure the channel details
        _id: '$channel._id',
        channelUsername: '$channel.channelUsername',
        channelUserId: '$channel.channelUserId',
      },
      pageComments: {   // Structure the comments
        _id: 1,
        commenter: 1,
        commenterId: 1,
        commentId: 1,
        content: 1,
        postContent: '$pageComments.postContent.message',  // Access the message field from postContent
      },
      posts: 1,   // Include posts array
      page: {   // Structure the page details
        pageId: '$page.pageId',
        name: '$page.name',
        category: '$page.category',
        likesCount: '$page.likesCount',
        postsCount: '$page.postsCount',
        pictureUrl: '$page.pictureUrl',
        weeklyInsights: '$page.weeklyInsights',
        monthlyInsights: '$page.monthlyInsights',
        monthlyPostsInsights: '$page.monthlyPostsInsights',
      },
    },
  },
]);

I tried to access it using '$pageComments.postContent.message', but I received an array of messages associated with all the posts. The expected result should be the message of the post related to that specific comment.

Copy some sample documents into a playground to show your aggregate working. There is lot going on so some sample documents would make a world of difference in you getting some assistance. Paste a link to your playground into your question so someone can help you debug.
